# Uiview as subview containing uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview

I have a button inside a view and when click on that button a subview appears .The subview contains a tableview.When click on tableview cell the text view inside the contentview gets enabled.So i am not able to select a table row..None of the actions on the subview happening..How to resolve this?

Comment: text view inside the contentview gets enabled.... what do you mean?

Comment: use textView.enabled=NO;

Comment: please clear your question ... post some code and description...

Comment: i meant the subviews tableview action is not being called but instead the main views action is happening..The main view contains the textview...the subview contains the tableview in the same position as mainview's textview.So when i touch on tableview ,the action happens like i have touched on textview(keyboard appears like taht..)the table view not getting the touch.

Comment: set your tableview as a superview like ie. [self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourTableview];

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UITextView and overwrite canBecomeFirstResponder:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: you are something worng with show tableview as subview...you not set is fist responder or something..

Answer (score 0):

Give the delegate and datasource to your `UITableview` and set as a superview like bellow..

```
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourTableview];
```

may be this answer is helpful to you...

:)